# Problematic Nginx config

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, hhvm, hiphop

I have setup the following ngnix config for my Ubuntu 14.04 VPS running HHVM with ngnix:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /home/lephenix/main_website;
index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;
include hhvm.conf;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&amp;$args;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}
}
```

Problem is that when I enable this config I get an error from ngnix:

```
2014/09/07 13:16:01 [emerg] 13584#0: unknown directive "index.php" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:6
```

I have looked and this seems to be the correct structure for this configuration. Even when I remove index.php the error then changes to:

```
2014/09/07 13:17:03 [emerg] 13648#0: unknown directive "index.html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:6
```

I followed the following guide to setup the server:
http://webdevstudios.com/2014/07/17/setting-up-wordpress-nginx-hhvm-for-the-fastest-possible-load-times/

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Yes Rudie, the line above handles IPv4, I believe.

Comment: Wow, I think I need to remove that then!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm
```

The directive is "index".

Also, the "try_files" is wrong.  Change to:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args
```

Also it's much nicer to have the config file indented properly. It makes it much easier to debug.

I suspect the tutorial that you followed is wrong, it's certainly not valid as directives need to be named first before trying to assign something to it.

Pop a note to the tutorial author maybe? It'd be nice for them to correct it so nobody else falls on this one :)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! So I put that in but now i'm getting an error on http://pastebin.com/w1mnJRKX Ngnix is reporting 2014/09/07 13:42:59 [emerg] 1587#0: unknown directive "$args" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:15 any ideas?

Comment: You can test nginx config with `nginx -t`. It should tell you something useful.

Comment: I think you need a new tutorial to follow :)  Nginx is picking up the ";" in "&amp;" as the end of the present directive, so it thinks $args is a new directive.

Comment: try_files should be try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args